# looking forward to /for interview timings

Tags: grammar

I am writing an confirmation mail to interview call over email

I just want to know if its right to say,

**I look forward for Interview scheduled**.

Comment: Perhaps 'I look forward to the scheduled interview'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One *looks forward to something* but not *forward for something*. In your case, you can write *I look forward to the interview* since the interview has been scheduled. Otherwise, it is customary to say *I look forward to hearing from you*.

Comment: I am replying as confirmation mail to scheduled interview

Comment: Is  right to say  <b>I look forward to the scheduled Interview.</b> . As interview has already been scheduled

Comment: @pilot Yes. It is right.

Answer (score 5):

"I look forward to the scheduled Interview" is grammatically correct, but to me (as a native British English speaker) it doesn't feel natural. I wouldn't include the word "scheduled". It's unnecessary - what other interview would you be looking forward to other than the one that's scheduled?

Sounds like it's a phone or Skype interview and they've emailed asking you to be available at a specific time. If so I would reply: "Thank you for your email and I confirm I will be available for interview on [date] at [time] [+ whatever else you need to confirm, phone number etc]. I look forward to speaking to you then" [or "on Tuesday" etc].